# Tomtom webfleet order api gives 40 general error

Tags: python, python-requests, tomtom

I am trying to insert a destination order using action=insertDestinationOrder
I am using POST method with all required parameters, but keep getting

```
{
    "errorCode": 40,
    "errorMsg": "general error"
}
```

I have checked using postman too. But still same.

Below is the request using python requests package.

```
import requests

url = "https://csv.telematics.tomtom.com/extern"

payload = "orderid=TO0049&country=DE&city=Cologne&latitude=50974519&ordertype=delivery%20order&zip=50735&longitude=6977319&street=Am%20Niehler%20Hafen%20%26%20Stapelkai%2C%2050735%20Cologne%20(Niehl)&account=XXXX&username=XXXX&password=XXXX&apikey=XXXX&lang=en&action=insertDestinationOrder&ordertext=Am%20Niehler%20Hafen%20%26%20Stapelkai%2C%2050735%20Cologne%20(Niehl)&useUTF8=true&outputformat=json"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Need some help.

Comment: You probably need some token to seperate the url and the payload, normally a `?`:

Comment: @Nordle, I have checked, now getting 405 method not found error

Comment: The error means that you are attempting to pass back a file that does not have the necessary permissions on the server to receive Post information from another script.

Comment: @Nordle, Thts right, But tomtom webfleet api suggests same format for creating orders.

Comment: Below is the link to api https://telematics.tomtom.com/static/help/webfleet-connect/en_gb/index.htm#insertDestinationOrderExtern.htm

Comment: My bad, ordertype was supposed to be a nonnegative integer and i was passing char. Now order got created using API.

Comment: @Nordle, Thanks bro !

Comment: Glad it worked! Welcome bro!

Comment: I added it as an answer if you wanted to accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `?` to the end of the url, **or** to the start of the payload:

```
url = "https://csv.telematics.tomtom.com/extern?"
```

or

```
payload = "?orderid=TO0049&country=DE&city=Cologne&latitude=50974519&ordertype=delivery%20order&zip=50735&longitude=6977319&street=Am%20Niehler%20Hafen%20%26%20Stapelkai%2C%2050735%20Cologne%20(Niehl)&account=XXXX&username=XXXX&password=XXXX&apikey=XXXX&lang=en&action=insertDestinationOrder&ordertext=Am%20Niehler%20Hafen%20%26%20Stapelkai%2C%2050735%20Cologne%20(Niehl)&useUTF8=true&outputformat=json"
```